# How to call a python package managed by Anaconda in matlab environment?

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda

I would like to call a python code in main matlab environment on linux platform.

**main matlab program:**

```
[status,cmdout] = system('python featurextraction.py')
```

**error1**

[image]

Because Bob package including `bob.bio.base` is managed by Anaconda, I guess that I should run `[status,cmdout] = system('conda info --envs')` and `[status,cmdout] = system('source activate bob')` in matlab program in advance just like,

**main matlab program**

```
[status,cmdout] = system('conda info --envs')
[status,cmdout] = system('source activate bob')
[status,cmdout] = system('python featurextraction.py')
```

**error2**

[image]

Could you tell me how to run `featurextraction.py` in python language in MATLAB? Because my matlab version is R2012a, I can't call python from MATLAB like the method directly, https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/call-python-from-matlab.html, which might need the version after a release of R2015a.

Thank you.

Jinfang

Comment: Sometime ago I used some python function via system command as well. I remember that I had some problems calling py-scripts and other custuome shell scripts. This was mainly due to the fact the system command in Matlab has a different PATH as your terminal/shell. Also certains libraries were not linked which had to be done manually.

Comment: Instead of trying to activate the environment as you would do at the command line, what happens if you specify the full path to the Python executable in the directory for the conda environment you want to use?

Comment: Nekomatic is right you should try to specify the full path. Here is an example how I had to do it on my mac `env_variable='/sw/bin:/opt/X11/bin';
system(['env PATH=' env_variable ' LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr /<path_to_file>/py_script.py ' filename]`. However the env_variable depends on your function and the libraries you need.